# delete all words with more than 4 letters in a string (Pascal)?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I was assigned a task for university where I have to write a program which deletes all words with more than 4 letters. I really have no clue at all. I would be very thankful for any kind of help.

```
VAR
UserString: string; //должна быть строка на 40 символов и точку в конце
i, n: byte;

BEGIN
Writeln('Enter the string:');
Readln(UserString);

i:=0;
n:=1;    

repeat       //MAIN LOOP:

  inc(i);
  if (UserString[i] = ' ') or (UserString[i] = '.') then

     begin
        if (i-n<3)then
        begin
        delete(UserString, n, i-n+1);
        i:=n-1;
        end;
        n:=i+1
     end

until (UserString[i] = '.') or (i>length(UserString));

Writeln('Result String: ', UserString);
END.
```

I tried this. and its working on onlinegdb but not on Delphi... and I don't know why...

Comment: The idea of homework is that you do it yourself to learn and train. "_I don't know why_" is too broad/vague as question. Put comments into your code which instructions you understand and which you don't. Prefer using better variable names instead of only `i` and `n`. Consider using [links](https://www.onlinegdb.com) here on the internet.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: both Delphi 7 and [GDB online](https://www.onlinegdb.com) output `Eins sieben acht neunzehn drei.` unchanged, not eliminating any word that is too long. Also keep in mind Delphi needs `uses Sysutils;` as per console application.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site, not a homework service. Please take the [tour] and read the [help], particularly [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/)

Comment: You say: *I really have no clue at all*. Yet, the code you present clearly does something similar to your task. I guess your code is a copy of another, already solved task, maybe *delete all words with less than 3 letters ...*. If you are motivated to learn, it should be fairly easy to study each line, try to understand what it does, and modify as needed to fulfill the *requirements in your assignment*. Execute the program in debug mode, line by line, to see the flow of the code and how the values of the variables change.

Answer (score 1):

You should break up the logic into smaller utility functions for each task you need (finding a word, getting the word's length, deleting the word and any subsequent whitespace, etc).  It will make the code easier to read and maintain.

For example:

```pascal
function FindNextWordStart(const S: string; var Index: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(S);
  while (Index <= Len) and (Ord(S[Index]) <= 32) do Inc(Index);
  Result := (Index <= Len);
end;

function GetWordLength(const S: string; Index: Integer): Integer;
var
  StartIdx, Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(S);
  StartIdx := Index;
  while (Index <= Len) and (Ord(S[Index]) > 32) do Inc(Index);
  Result := (Index - StartIdx);
end;

procedure DeleteWord(var S: String; Index, WordLen: Integer);
var
  StartIdx, Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(S);
  StartIdx := Index;
  Inc(Index, WordLen);
  while (Index <= Len) and (Ord(S[Index]) <= 32) do Inc(Index);
  Delete(S, StartIdx, Index - StartIdx);
end;

var
  UserString: string;
  StartIdx, WordLen: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('Enter the string:');
  Readln(UserString);

  StartIdx := 1;
  while FindNextWordStart(UserString, StartIdx) do
  begin
    WordLen := GetWordLength(UserString, StartIdx);
    if WordLen > 4 then
      DeleteWord(UserString, StartIdx, WordLen)
    else
      Inc(StartIdx, WordLen);
  end;

  Writeln('Result String: ', UserString);
end.
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/MXWTiA6gS)

Comment: For a beginner I guess this is too cryptic and requires knowing what procedures/functions/parameters are. While you and I need no comments and know what _the magic number_ `32` means in here it should be way over the head for a newcomer.

Comment: The instructor at the OP's school is going to read this and immediately fail the assignment, because it's clearly well beyond the OP's knowledge. At least it can serve as a lesson to the OP about copy/pasting their assignments.

Comment: Good point, deleted my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you can solve your task with TStringlist class:

```
uses Classes;
    ......
    var  AStrLst : TStringlist ;
         i : Integer ,
    begin
        AStrLst := TStringlist.Create ;
        try
           //  use  this char for separation  of words 
           AStrLst.Delimiter :=' ';
           AStrLst.DelimitedText := ' here comes my sample string ';
    
           for I := AStrLst.Count-1 to 0 do
              begin
              //  delete item from list  if ...
              if length( trim(AStrLst[i])) <= 4  then AStrLst.Delete(i);
              end;
        finally
           //    get  the complete
           writeln ( AStrLst.Text ) ;
           AStrLst.Free;
        end;
    end;
```

I did  not test  this code - but hope it helps - to get this code running, your home work

Comment: Without `uses` the `TStringList` is unknown to any Pascal compiler - I'm sure so many code posters never include that important line because they're not aware of it themselves anymore, with Delphi pre-filling it as per a new project.

Comment: I use this  : https://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=TStringList

Comment: [Q.e.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) No, you are using the "_Classes unit_" and it should be in the code which units are required.